# Attempting to get sequential div containers to not overlap previous no wrap text box without specifying fixed width

Tags: css, css-float, word-wrap

I know there have been a quite a few like this on here and other sites already, but am kicking myself over this and really should have solved this issue by now - so here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/p3reauLf/1/

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.vert-text {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vert-text"><strong>TRAX</strong></div>
  <div class="info"><strong>A1.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 1)<br>
    <strong>B1.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 2)<br>
    <strong>B2.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 3)<br></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vert-text"><strong>DATA</strong></div>
  <div class="info"><strong>Label:</strong> Vicious Muzik Records<br>
    <strong>Released:</strong> 1994<br>
    <strong>Condition:</strong> VG+ to NM-<br></div>
</div>
```

In this JS fiddle you can see the 2 boxes side by side with text (dynamic on my web site) where the text appears to be overlapped by the second box - and i have no clue how to make the width of the boxes adjust to size of the text within -

of course i would like the box on the right to remain to the right of the first box, unless of course the page gets to narrow in which case it bumps down under the 1st box -

at least that is what i am trying to achieve - live page here:

on this live page i have adjusted to the width to be fixed, but sometimes text is longer or much shorter and it either gets truncated or is too long and looks off...

appreciate all the help i can get ! thanks

Comment: So i think the vertical text box that i have put into each container div is the issue here, its taking it into account as part of the width of the contents and overlapping that amount horizontally on the right where the next box starts - i also think its taking it into account as if it was not vertical, because the dimensions is closer to it when left as horizontal text and not made to be vertical as i have it - maybe what this needs is a tweak in the HTML but im thinking there must be some sort of CSS option too - perhaps a CSS display option to use for vertical text ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modern CSS grid layout mode, and create two columns in a media query with the breakpoint of your choosing:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.vert-text {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.info {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flow-root;
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vert-text"><strong>TRAX</strong></div>
  <div class="info"><strong>A1.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 1)<br>
    <strong>B1.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 2)<br>
    <strong>B2.</strong> Activator (Untitled Mix 3)<br></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="vert-text"><strong>DATA</strong></div>
  <div class="info"><strong>Label:</strong> Vicious Muzik Records<br>
    <strong>Released:</strong> 1994<br>
    <strong>Condition:</strong> VG+ to NM-<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok just understood how your code works :) will see what i can do ! thanks again ... for now ... till i return.